# make a request to a nats group

Tags: go, nats.io

here is my sub.go example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    nats "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)

type Message struct {
    Status string `json:"Status"`
    Msg    string `json:"Msg"`
}

type Response struct {
    Status string `json:"Status"`
    Msg    string `json:"Msg"`
}

var nc *nats.Conn
var c *nats.EncodedConn

func start(){
    nc, _ := nats.Connect("127.0.0.1:4222")
    c, _ := nats.NewEncodedConn(nc, nats.JSON_ENCODER)
    c.QueueSubscribe("subject_toto", "queue_titi", func(_, reply string, message  *Message) {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", message)
        var response Response
        response.Msg = "message received"
        response.Status = "Ok"
        c.Publish("reply", response)
        c.Flush()
    })
    c.Flush()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("begin")
    go start()
    defer c.Close()
    fmt.Scanln()
    nc.Drain()
    // Close connection
    nc.Close()
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

And it runs perfectly, so now I woud like to publish a message to this queue, here is my pub.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    nats "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
    "time"
)

type Message struct {
    Status string `json:"Status"`
    Msg    string `json:"Msg"`
}

type Response struct {
    Status string `json:"Status"`
    Msg    string `json:"Msg"`
}

var nc *nats.Conn
var c *nats.EncodedConn

func start(){
    var err error
    var message Message
    var response Response
    nc, _ := nats.Connect("127.0.0.1:4222")
    c, _ := nats.NewEncodedConn(nc, nats.JSON_ENCODER)
    message.Status = "Ok"
    message.Msg = "hello"
    err = c.Request("subject_toto", message, &response, 6*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n","response")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", response)
    defer c.Close()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("begin")
    start()
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

But when I try to publish to it I have an empty response:

> response {Status: Msg:}

One of the beginning of an answer seems to use PublishRequest but it seems to I can send only string to the server and not a struct.

Comment: Have you tried `c.Flush()` after sending your reply with `c.Publish`?

Comment: @TehSphinX yes i've edited my post it seems that i have an empty response now :) thanks i'am progressing.

Comment: I strongly suggest you handle all the errors you are ignoring currently (e.g. log them). It might shed some light on why it's not working. e.g.  errors while connecting,  subscribing, publishing, flushing, etc.

Comment: Also get rid of the global connection variables... bad idea!

Comment: Note: subscription is not blocking, so no goroutine is needed for the `start` function.

Comment: `c.Publish("reply", response)`: "reply" should actually be `message.Reply`. That is the address the reply needs to be sent to.

Comment: @TehSphinX i found a solution and it's working thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yup, or use `msg.Respond` to repond to the message ;) That works, too.

Comment: @TehSphinX i will ask if there is a better way to do it without the json decoding part in an other question. Thanks again

Comment: Was wondering the same thing, since you are using an `EncodedConn` already. Note: In my code i'm doing it manually, but I'm not using the encoded connection.

Comment: Hmmm... from this example it looks like you just have to put the correct function with the correct paramenter type as input:

https://github.com/nats-io/nats.go#encoded-connections

// Go type Subscriber
c.Subscribe("hello", func(p *person) {
    fmt.Printf("Received a person: %+v\n", p)
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
c.Publish("reply", response)
```

When you send a request and your subscriber is going to respond, there should be a "reply-to subject" that is called inbox. This inbox is set in the `reply` arg of handler function.

So you have to publish your response into the subject that is returned by the `reply` arg of the handler function in `QueueSubscribe()`, so change that line into:

```
c.Publish(reply, response)
```

The value of reply arg is important for communication and is something like this: `_INBOX.bw5EtJShBTI9OQdvxFOBlz.VxsGBcjH`

Comment: yes it's the "clean" way that i wanted to know thanks @meshkati

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functionning version of sub :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    nats "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)
type Message struct {
    Status string `json:"Status"`
    Msg    string `json:"Msg"`
}

type Response struct {
    Status string `json:"Status"`
    Msg    string `json:"Msg"`
}

var nc *nats.Conn
var c *nats.EncodedConn


func start(){

    nc, _ := nats.Connect("127.0.0.1:4222")
    c, _ := nats.NewEncodedConn(nc, nats.JSON_ENCODER)
    c.QueueSubscribe("subject_toto", "queue_titi",func(msg *nats.Msg) {
        var message Message
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(msg.Data), &message)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", "message from pub")
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", message)
        var response Response
        response.Msg = "message received"
        response.Status = "Ok"
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", "response to  sub")
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", response)
        byteConfApi, err2 := json.Marshal(response)
        if err2 != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", err2)
        }
        msg.Respond(byteConfApi)
        c.Flush()
    })
}



func main(){
    fmt.Println("begin")
    go  start()
    defer c.Close()
    fmt.Scanln()
    nc.Drain()
    // Close connection
    nc.Close()
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```